# add a div at the end of wp_nav_menu function in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, menu

I want to add a div at the bottom of the wordpress wp_nav_menu so it will look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>

  <div class="my-div"></div>
</ul>
```

I can't seem to find a way to do it in the function document on wordpress, can anyone please help?

Comment: where is your PHP code ? please add `wp_nav_menu` code in you question.

Comment: Well my code is just 
<? php wp_nav_menu() ?>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
   wp_nav_menu( 
                 array(
                        'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s <div class="my-div"></div></ul>'
                      )
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```html
wp_nav_menu(array('items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s <div class="my-div"></div></ul>',));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace **`items_wrap`** with below line

```
 wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s <div class="my-div"></div></ul>',
                ));
```